# Unity coroutine does not work

Tags: c#, unityscript, coroutine, unity-game-engine

I don't think I fully understand coroutines, it doesn't work the way I wanted, so I need help.

I've got a memory game (Simon like) that consist of 4 squares that randomly switches on and off. After square switches on/off it should take a little break, before switching next button, which my program does not seem to do so. For the switching process I use blink*Colorname coroutine which is following:

```
 foreach (int color in pattern) 
 {
      switch (color) 
      {
          case 0:
              StartCoroutine (blinkGreen (blinkSeconds));
              break;
          case 1:
              StartCoroutine (blinkRed (blinkSeconds));
              break;
          default:
              break;
       }
 }
 //to do: pause function between button blinks

 IEnumerator blinkGreen (float seconds)
 {
      greenImg.color = Color.white;
      yield return new WaitForSeconds (seconds);
      greenImg.color = Color.green;
 }
```

I've tried using waitforseconds at 2 places to achieve my goal: First, at blink*Color as following:

```
 IEnumerator blinkGreen (float seconds)
 {
     greenImg.color = Color.white;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds (seconds);
     greenImg.color = Color.green;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds (seconds);
 }
```

Second, after the the loop, under //to do: pause function between button blinks by calling another coroutine:

```
     StartCoroutine(waitfornexttransition(5.0f));

     IEnumerator waitfornexttransition (float second)
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds (second);
     }
```

Am I missing something? All suggestions and helps are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not wait for the completion of the started coroutine to continue code execution. If you type (psuedocode):

```
print "1"
start coroutine that prints "2" after a second
print "3"
```

the output will be: "1", "3", "2".

If you put all your code in one coroutine, everything will run sequentially as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it's all in a foreach loop anyway and you're starting a new couroutine for each iteration, then basically all the coroutines are starting at the same time within the same frame. They will then all run concurrently regardless of what the rest of your code is doing, blinking all lights simultaneously.

If you want your code to wait for a certain amount of time between executions, then make a timer and only blink the lights when the timer hits 0. A basic example would be:

```
private float timer;

void Start()
{
    timer = 2f; // Waiting 2 seconds between blinks
}

void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;  // Consistently decrement timer independently of frame rate

    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        blinkLight();
        timer = 2f;
    }
}

void blinkLight()
{
    // Light blinking logic goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loop should also be inside a coroutine and you can put a `yield return new WaitForSeconds (seconds)` before each iteration.